# Accidentally deleted java and now all my eclipse programs dont have java libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

I had recently installed a new version of jdk and decided to delete the old one from control panel. After doing so, all of my projects now don't seem to have java libraries. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Install it again.

Comment: Don't panic. Add the new JDK to your **Installed JREs** preference page and update the Java Build Paths in your projects accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just install it again. Follow the correct steps when you install because path of environment variables should be updated with new JDK.

Comment: I fixed the problem by configuring the build path but I'll keep this in mind for next time. Thank you!